# Zend_Acl - Role per resource

Tags: zend-framework, zend-acl

I'm trying to implement Zend_Acl.

I've never used it before and whilst I can get basic acl stuff working on the controller/action level, I need users to have different roles on different projects, say admin, editor, etc.

So a user could create projects and they would be able edit/delete their own projects, but they may also be invited by another user as an 'Editor' on the other persons project, so they'd be able to edit that project, but not delete it, or they could be a 'Viewer' and not be able to edit/delete only view that project.

Would I have to do this with assertions, has anyone got any pointers?

Answer (score 2):

Maybe Dynamic Assertions solve your problems. Take a look at these videos:

http://alex-tech-adventures.com/development/zend-framework/91-acl-dynamic-assertions.html

http://alex-tech-adventures.com/development/zend-framework/62-allocation-resources-and-permissions-with-zendacl.html

http://alex-tech-adventures.com/development/zend-framework/68-zendregistry-and-authentication-improvement.html